# Jquery populate text box value based on selectbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have a text box for entering a decimal weight for a barrel that carries leftover chemicals.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
     <div class="input-group ">
         <span class="input-group-addon white">Weight</span>
         <input class="form-control weight" type="text" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Then the user will select an option from a selectbox for what size of barrel it is.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group ">
        <span class="input-group-addon white">Barrel Size</span>
        <select class="form-control gray" id="sizeSelect">
            <option value="defaultSelect" disabled selected>Select an option..</option>
            <option value="Small">Small</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Large">Large</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each barrel size already has a set weight. Small = 2.5kg, Medium = 4.5kg, Large = 8.5kg.
What I then have is a 3rd textbox that I want to display the chemical weight after it subtracts the barrel weight.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group ">
        <span class="input-group-addon white">Updated Weight</span>
        <input readonly class="form-control updatedWeight" style="color: #20c200" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I basically am trying something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#sizeSelect').change(function() {
    var myText = $("#sizeSelect :selected").text();
    if (myText == 'Small') {
     //Something like:
       var sum = $('.weight').val() - 2.5;
       $('.updatedWeight').val() = sum;
    }
});
```

});

I'm a bit lost as I'm new to jquery. Please any tips are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I believe to set a value with JQuery you pass the value to the val() function, like: `...val(sum);`. I'm not sure what other issues you might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use data attributes to set the weight of each barrel, so like

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group ">
        <span class="input-group-addon white">Barrel Size</span>
        <select class="form-control gray" id="sizeSelect">
            <option value="defaultSelect" disabled selected>Select an option..</option>
            <option value="Small" data-weight=2.5>Small</option>
            <option value="Medium" data-weight=4.5>Medium</option>
            <option value="Large" data-weight=8.5>Large</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then you could do the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sizeSelect').change(function() {
        var newWeight = $("#weight").val() - $("#sizeSelect:selected").data("weight");
        $('.updatedWeight').val(orgWeight)
    });
    $('#weight').change(function() {
        var newWeight = $("#weight").val() - $("#sizeSelect:selected").data("weight");
        $('.updatedWeight').val(orgWeight)
    });
});
```

To update the value in the updatedWeight each time an update is made to either the weight input or the sizeSelect.
Also, change the weight input to have an id instead of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('.updatedWeight').val(sum);` to change value of `input`